# get keyCode on click?

Tags: jquery

first, see my example : http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/gkeAM/

i want get keyCode when click on link .

i want found that when clicked on link, ctrl key pressed or not ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
        if(e.ctrlKey)
        {
            alert( 'You pressed ctrl key' );
        }
        else
        {
            alert( 'You clicked on link without ctrl key' );
        }
        return false;
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gkeAM/2/)

Comment: SuperTramp, you beat me to it